# Optimize image aliasing in old browser?

Tags: javascript

I have images that are downscaled for showing them in the browser.

In modern standalone browsers the images look very nice.

But in old, they are somehow a bit distored, especially straight lines within an image.

See the following example. Left is modern, right is old browser. You can especially see the problem regarding the sunbed.
[Link to image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0qVi9D7R5MZZW55ZFR4WnhpWUk/view?usp=sharing)

Is there anything one can do to optimize this?

Comment: Where are you downscaling images?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Never scale images in browser.

Comment: I'm getting the images from a `REST` api and want to show them in the browser, but not in original size. I therefore have no chance not scaling in the browser.

Comment: You can write a wrapper script on your own server, which gets images from the REST api and rescales the images via a server side script.

Comment: But then I would have to *host* the images that I converted, don't I? I definitly don't want this.